# Error con instalacion de npm install en distintas versiones

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, packages

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue 3 y por necesidad de otro proyecto en laravel instale la ultima version de nodejs, especificamente la 18.9.1, anterior a esta tenia la version 16.17.1 LTS, luego de esta actualización al correr el proyecto de vue nuevamente me comenzo a dar error, que no era la misma version de nodejs, hasta ahi todo bien, es lo normal que me pasaba cuando venia actualizando la version, simplemente eliminaba la carpeta node_modules y volvia a instalar y correr el proyecto nuevamente, pero ahora no tengo solución, por mas que intento me da error en un paquete u otro, he eliminado

Eliminando node_modules
Eliminando package-lock.json
Limpiando cache
Vuelto a instalar npm install.
He revisado varios post, pero no logro pasar la instalación

```
PS C:\DEV C\keyappfront> npm install 
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN Found: postcss@7.0.39
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN   dev postcss@"^7.0.39" from the root project
npm WARN   45 more (@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat, autoprefixer, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN   postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.2.17
npm WARN   node_modules/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat
npm WARN   1 more (tailwindcss)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: postcss@8.4.16
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN   peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN   node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN     postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.2.17
npm WARN     node_modules/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat
npm WARN     1 more (tailwindcss)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mipc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-26T23_34_53_350Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\DEV C\keyappfront>
```

algunas veces se cae en el paquete svgo o en el hapi...

De que forma podria solucionar el problema?

Revisando un poco el log encuentro estos registros:

```
13691 timing reifyNode:node_modules/serve-index Completed in 20756ms
13692 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue/-/vue-3.2.39.tgz 18864ms (cache miss)
13693 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/traverse/-/traverse-7.19.1.tgz 18916ms (cache miss)
13694 timing reifyNode:node_modules/vue Completed in 20604ms
13695 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/traverse Completed in 20623ms
13696 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/expect/-/expect-24.9.0.tgz 19526ms (cache miss)
13697 timing reifyNode:node_modules/expect Completed in 20836ms
13698 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer/-/autoprefixer-9.8.8.tgz 19296ms (cache miss)
13699 timing reifyNode:node_modules/autoprefixer Completed in 21033ms
13700 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/vue3 1232ms (cache miss)
13701 timing metavuln:packument:vue3 Completed in 1233ms
13702 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
13702 verbose stack     at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
13702 verbose stack     at Advisory.load (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\advisory.js:109:33)
13702 verbose stack     at Calculator.[calculate] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\metavuln-calculator\lib\index.js:60:14)
13702 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 0)
13702 verbose stack     at async Map.[init] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:186:9)
13702 verbose stack     at async Map.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\audit-report.js:109:7)
13703 verbose cwd C:\DEV C\keyappfront
13704 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
13705 verbose node v16.17.1
13706 verbose npm  v8.15.0
13707 error Cannot convert undefined or null to object
13708 verbose exit 1
13709 timing npm Completed in 89287ms
13710 verbose unfinished npm timer command:install 1664236834938
13711 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1664236834941
13712 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:audit 1664236902815
13713 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:unpack 1664236902834
13714 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/deasync 1664236902839
13715 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/es-abstract 1664236902888
13716 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/csso/node_modules/css-tree 1664236902890
13717 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/css-tree 1664236902890
13718 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties 1664236902897
13719 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/async 1664236902905
13720 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/cssstyle 1664236902912
13721 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve 1664236902914
13722 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/jsdom 1664236902917
13723 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@jest/core 1664236902944
13724 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/rxjs 1664236902953
13725 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/clean-css 1664236902955
13726 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/ajv 1664236902964
13727 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/highlight.js 1664236902974
13728 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/neo-async 1664236902975
13729 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/babel-runtime 1664236902979
13730 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js 1664236902980
13731 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/caniuse-lite 1664236902985
13732 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/prettier 1664236902986
13733 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@types/node 1664236902992
13734 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen/node_modules/cssstyle 1664236903012
13735 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen/node_modules/jsdom 1664236903013
13736 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/globby/node_modules/fast-glob 1664236903016
13737 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/runtime 1664236903028
13738 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/webpack 1664236903029
13739 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/resolve 1664236903032
13740 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/types 1664236903040
13741 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@babel/core 1664236903043
13742 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/typescript 1664236903043
13743 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/tailwindcss 1664236903043
13744 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/moment 1664236903044
13745 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/lodash 1664236903044
13746 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue 1664236903044
13747 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/core-js 1664236903044
13748 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/node_modules/vue 1664236903048
13749 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/eslint 1664236903048
13750 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat 1664236903049
13751 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/chart.js 1664236903050
13752 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@heroicons/vue 1664236903050
13753 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/@headlessui/vue 1664236903050
13754 verbose unfinished npm timer auditReport:init 1664236905793
13755 verbose unfinished npm timer metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:vue3:OmalegdT6VFjZzWcuj7bjCj2phHiYuPLpqT+Xf425l7PYl9rM1ENYtg2w57ySnboGCDrTTQ43VgFKha6ejqfRQ== 1664236922886
13756 verbose unfinished npm timer metavuln:load:security-advisory:vue3:OmalegdT6VFjZzWcuj7bjCj2phHiYuPLpqT+Xf425l7PYl9rM1ENYtg2w57ySnboGCDrTTQ43VgFKha6ejqfRQ== 1664236924119
13757 verbose code 1
13758 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
13758 error     C:\Users\mipc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-27T00_00_34_836Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Y qué sale en ese log que te indica al final?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo he actualizado el post con parte del log que obtengo

Comment: Me parece que el problema radica en tailwind como tal, ¿Qué versión tienes?